# Programmatically distorting text in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, pathgeometry

I am trying to programmatically draw a distorted string of text with C# using different sets of APIs (WinForms, WPF, and Windows Phone 8).

Using WinForms, I managed to achieve this with GDI+'s `System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath` class this way:

```
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath path = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath();
path.AddString(text, font.FontFamily, (int)font.Style, font.Size, new Drawing::Point(0, 0), Drawing::StringFormat.GenericDefault);
PointF[] origPoints = path.PathPoints;
PointF[] newPoints = new PointF[originalPath.PointCount];
/* Generate the values of newPoints items from origPoints items */
System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath distortion = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath(newPoints, path.PathTypes);

/* ...Create Graphics object... */

graphics.FillPath(Drawing::Brushes.Black, distortion);
```

Using WPF, I managed to achieve this by creating a `System.Windows.Media.Geometry` from a `System.Windows.Media.FormattedText`, converting it to a `PathGeometry` via a `System.Windows.Shapes.Path`, then manually creating an unfrozen deep copy of its `Figures` property and modifying every `Point` in every `PolyLineSegment` in every `PathFigure` of the `PathGeometry`. It looks something like this:

```
FormattedText formattedText = new Media::FormattedText(text, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
            Windows::FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
            typeface, fontSize, Media::Brushes.Transparent);
Geometry geom = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new Point(0, 0));

Path path = new Path();
path.Data = geom;
PathGeometry pathGeom = path.Data.GetFlattenedPathGeometry();
PathGeometry newGeom = new PathGeometry(); /* Cloned geometry. We can't modify the original - it's frozen */

newGeom.Figures = pathGeom.Figures.Clone();
/* Etc... Clone the Segments for each Figure, then the Points for every Segment */

/* ...Create DrawingContext... */

context.DrawGeometry(Media::Brushes.Black, null, newGeom);
```

I tried porting the latter solution to Windows Phone (Windows Phone 8), but I found out it's missing `FormattedText`, `DrawingContext`, `Geometry.GetFlattenedPathGeometry()` and the `Clone` methods for collections of `Figure`s, `Segment`s and `Point`s (also, it's missing out on `RenderTargetBitmap` and `DrawingVisual` and I haven't the slightest idea on how and where will I render the modified `Geometry`, but that can be seen as a separate issue).

How can I port my WPF code to Windows Phone 8? What are the alternatives I can use to build a `Geometry` from a text string, get a `PathGeometry` from my `Geometry`, and how can I `Clone` its contents?

Or is there a better option for programmatically distorting text on Windows Phone 8?